# Nested menu keeps dissapearing on IE 8 & 9

Tags: html, css

I used this menu as a template for my own :

http://ago.tanfa.co.uk/css/examples/menu/hs7.html

I used the same technique as this menu I just changed the css like colors/fonts size etc. Now the issue I have is that when I hover root items like 'CSS Drop Down Menus' in the example from the link.

The sub menu dissapears if I don't jump to the menu really quickly, and its driving me nuts. Did anyone have similar issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this behavior is because of top `margin` or positioning (like `top: 2px` on an `absolute` or `relative` element) on the submenus that is creating a "gap" between the main menu item and the submenu. Without your actual code posted, that is the only advice I can give.