# Nested nav link dissapears too quickly in IE 9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, nav

This question is exactly the same as another question: [Nested menu keeps dissapearing on IE 8 & 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270939/nested-menu-keeps-dissapearing-on-ie-8-9) but the solution is rather sparse. Why do my nested menus disappear before I can get my cursor to them unless I move it really fast? Only happens in IE (I've checked 8 and 9).

What I've tried:

IE9 supports HTML 5 and I've declared it at the top of the doc (well, below a block of php) so its not that. I've tried positioning just the nested `ul li a`'s slightly higher so that they overlap a bit (so there would be no gap) but it doesn't fix it. To see what it used to look like and how it behaved correctly click on "blog" in the nav bar. It still uses images instead of text in the nav

website is http://www.seventhheavenvintage.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question can be found here [Why does this img break hover state in ie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23860862/why-does-this-img-break-hover-state-in-ie) which is the same question to my same problem, just worded better. In short: apply a sufficiently negative margin.